# Phonegap File Upload: Empty request body & files

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova

Trying to upload an amr file from a mobile device to a server with Phonegap, using the [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) plugin.

```
var uri = "./" + $scope.audio.src;
$scope.audio.release();

var options = new FileUploadOptions();

options.fileKey = "audio";
options.fileName = uri.substr(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "audio/AMR";
options.httpMethod = "POST";
options.chunkedMode = false;

console.log("Options:", options);

options.params = {
    exhibitId: $scope.id,
    title: $scope.title,
    email: $scope.email
};

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(uri, encodeURI("http://someurl.com/api/recording/create"), 
    $scope.uploadSuccess, 
    $scope.uploadFailure, 
    options
);
```

Where audio is a [Media](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media) object.

Upon inspection at the server (nodejs), the request object's body and file properties are empty and the content-length in the headers is set to 0. Seems like the file is not being properly attached to the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you aren't setting your path properly. You need to use an absolute path in order to do this, you can use requestFileSystem with fullPath to get this information.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function(fileSystem){ 
        fileSystem.root.fullPath; 
});
```